# Bad gateway when deploying Django app with awsebcli

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I was using this AWS guideline to deploy the Django application to AWS EB using awsebcli.

[Deploying a Django application to Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html)

But after I finished all the steps I got "502 Bad Gateway" error and I don't see any environment created in the AWS console, but when I run `eb status` it looks like the environment was created.

`eb status`

```
Environment details for: django-test-env
  Application name: django-test
  Region: us-west-2
  Deployed Version: app-210819_194308
  Environment ID: e-2h9nu62f8t
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2::platform/Python 3.8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.4
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: django-test-env.eba-3i3hqgjc.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2021-08-19 18:43:34.097000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Red
```

The only thing I did differently was that I used Python 3.8 at Deploy your site with the EB CLI Step 1.

Also, I had to create an access key ID and secret access key, to be able to login to awsebcli.

Comment: Maybe you are checking wrong region or account in AWS console.

Comment: Please show us your django.config in .ebextensions. And please try what Marcin says.

Comment: Did you change your `WSGIPath` in your django.config when you chose to use Python 3.8?

Comment: It was wrong `WSGIPath` in `django.config`, since I just copied text from AWS instructions. It was a first time I used awsebcli and it was kinda furstrating. Now it's best friend once I figured out how to use it. Deployed Django 3.2 on Python 3.8 without any issues.